# Setting a twitter account in the iphone simulator

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, ios-simulator

I'm developing an iOS application, and to be able to retrieve data from Twitter, i need to set my Twitter account via `Settings` in the simulator to use Twitter framework. Even if i type my username and password correctly, it gives an error telling that `username or password is invalid` , but i'm 100 % sure that they are correct , because i'm using on the web. I'm able to access my Twitter account. The other weird issue that i'm facing this problem while using iphone 5.0 simulator. No problem with iphone 6.0 simulator.  It drives me crazy, lookep up on the web, but nothing came up. Do you guys any idea why i'm having this problem ?

Edit: I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.0 on Mountaion Lion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you use Xcode 4.6 Developer Preview 2? This is a known issue:

> When using the iOS 6.1 SDK on OS X v10.8 (Mountain Lion), if you use
>   the iOS 5.0 or iOS 5.1 “Legacy SDK” in iOS Simulator, you will not be
>   able to sign in to Twitter via the Settings pane and Twitter.framework
>   will not work correctly. If you need to test Twitter features, you
>   will need to choose either the iOS 6.1 or iOS 6.0 Simulator run
>   destination or test with iOS 5.x on a device. These problems do not
>   occur when running Simulator on OS X v10.7 (Lion).

Comment: but does the result of ios5 simulator & ios6.1 simulator the same ??
I dont have an device to test it..!

Answer (score 0):

I had a code done in Xcode 8.3.3 that I code look up tweets on a hashtag. I used the twitter built in Social app to login there then test my app. An update with Xcode 9.2 is that you cannot use the built in social apps like before in Xcode 8.X.X.

iOS 11 no longer supports using Twitter from the built-in social framework.

The solution is that you have to use Twitter Kit 3 to use Twitter features in your app like Tweet, Social Twitter login, and access or use any Twitter API.

link to twitter kit iOS:
https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki